# OOP - Is there a name for the design pattern of using class properties or lambdas to wrap static methods (of the same name)?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, static-methods, class-properties

I'm working with a C# class at the moment that exposes some lambda [instance] methods which serve as wrappers for static methods of the same name.

Here is an example snippet:

```cs
public class UserUI : DataUI
{
  // FYI: the `Context` object here is inherited from the `DataUI` base class
  public string GetUserId() => GetUserId(Context);

  public static string GetUserId(IDataUIContext context)
  {
    // ... logic here for pulling id from `context` ...
    return userId;
  }
}
```

I'm wondering: **is there a name for such a design pattern as this?**

---

Additionally, **would it be possible to accomplish the same functionality using a class property here rather than an instance method / lambda?**

Like so:

```cs
public class UserUI : DataUI
{
  public string GetUserId => GetUserId(Context);

  public static string GetUserId(IDataUIContext context)
  {
    // ... logic here for pulling id from `context` ...
    return userId;
  }
}
```

And, if so, is there any discernible difference between using a property / getter instead? (other than the method having to be invoked as opposed to being accessed like a field, obviously)

Comment: I don't understand what you gain by having a static version of the method? You can implement `public string GetUserId() { ... }` and don't need the second method

Comment: A (get-set) property's just special syntax for a pair of methods that read/write from/to the same field/storage and (seem to) go by the same name. So it doesn't make much difference if you use one or the other. There are not so little APIs however that prefer properties and can't handle methods (JSON/WPFdatabinding to name a few). If you don't have to comply to these, its a matter of taste. Properties in generally should run quick like a field access at best. Not to perform a lots of sub-steps other than get and return the value. As to the name of the pattern: The opposite would be: YAGNI ;)

Comment: Note that the expression-bodied member `public string GetUserId() => GetUserId(Context);` is nothing more than syntactic sugar for `public string GetUserId() { return GetUserId(Context); }`

Comment: @knittl I know this "pattern" from situations where you want to create a key out of several other variables, and in that class you also have a Key property (that uses the static Builder method one time). The static method is also useful for the client API that itself needs to build such keys and than compare them with the Key props of the owning class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now I can only think of a Proxy design pattern that can resemble what you have.

In the case when you need to present an object as an interface but your functionality implementation has only a static access, you can create a proxy such as

```cs
public static class Functionality  // may be in the different assembly
{
    public static string MethodA(IDataUIContext context)
    {
        // do something
    }
}

public interface IProxy
{
    string MethodA(IDataUIContext context);
}

public class Proxy : IProxy
{
    public string MethodA(IDataUIContext context) => Functionality.MethodA(context);
}
```

This is not a representation of the classic Go4 Proxy pattern but it is a variation

Continuation of this could be

```cs
public class Proxy2 : IProxy
{
    public string MethodA(IDataUIContext context) => AnotheFunctionality.ADifferentMethod(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this a design pattern? Not a classic [GoF](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/dp) one, but in general, this is just [partial application](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/01/30/partial-application-is-dependency-injection), a well-know feature of many functional programming languages.

In genreal, you can think of any procedure with the type type `public static string GetUserId(IDataUIContext context)` as (if you drop the `static` keyword) an implementation of a single-method interface with this the method

```
public interface IMyInteface
{
    string GetUserId(IDataUIContext context)
}
```

which corresponds to a `Func<IDataUIContext, string>`. If you then define a lambda expression that closes over the input (`IDataUIContext`), you essentiall have yourself a `string` value. That's partial application in a nutshell.

[Objects are just closures](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/02/12/object-isomorphisms), so effectively the `GetUserId` method can be viewed as a function or object.